# Loan - Early Repayment

Tags: finance

I have been having some difficulties with figuring out how to calculate for early repayment.

The question goes:
You take a 6 year loan of $25,000 with 7% annual interest rate and quarterly payments starting end of year 1.

I have solved for the quarterly loan payments = $1,284.64

Now comes the part that I am really confused about! If I decide to pay off the loan at time 3, how much would I have to pay including the time 3 payment, assuming no penalty for early repayment?

I have drawn up sections:

Q1:

Payment = 0 , Interest = 0, Principal = 0, Balance = 25,000

Q2:

PMT = 1,284.64, Interest = 437.50, Principal = 847.14, Balance = 24,152.86

Q3:

PMT = 1,284.64, Interest = 422.675, Principal = 861.964, Balance = 23,290.895

Y2Q1:

PMT = 1,284.64, Interest = 407.59, Principal = 877.049, Balance = 22,413.845

The answer is $15,081.10 but I can't seem to get to that. Is my method not it? Is there a formula  which does not require drawing up the sections? I do need some clarifications regarding what "time 3" means too, please.

Thank you all so much!

- Struggling Student

Comment: So you are saying that after 3 payments totaling around $3600 your payoff quote would be 15,000? Am I understanding the problem correctly? Maybe the answer is wrong

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).